# Is there an easy way to integrate scaladoc into IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, javadoc, scaladoc

How do I use/generate scaladoc from within IntelliJ Idea (running on ubuntu)? Most preferably I would like to configure Tools/generate javadoc to also generate scaladoc, though that might be hard as of the differences between both according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046582/generating-javadoc-for-project-involving-scala-modules).

Answer (score 10):

The scaladoc support in IntelliJ is pretty basic for now: some keywords are highlighted in comments, but there is no "generate scaladoc" option in tools. We'll create an issue in the tracker to keep it in mind.
Thanks.

Cheers!
Ilya